# Trying to catch a touch on a CALayer which is on top of my marker

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

My mapView has annotations on top of it, and some annotations have an extra `CALayer` on top of them.
The problem is that annotations that have these layers on top of them don't pass the touch on,  instead the view detects that a CALayer was tapped.

I am going to need a solution to make these CALayers "transparent to touches" so that I can tell which annotation was tapped.

- Is there a way to make the topmost CALayers transparent to touches somehow?
- Is there maybe another approach that will make it possible to detect the underlying annotation that was tapped?

Comment: How is this different from your previous question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The blocking CALayer was on top of a former CALAyer, 
it took only to access the ancestor - `theBlockingLayer.superlayer`.
By checking on the ancestor, I got all that I needed

Answer (score 1):

Try overriding these like this in your Layer subclass

```
- (CALayer *)hitTest:(CGPoint)thePoint
{
    return nil;
}
```

or this

```
- (BOOL)containsPoint:(CGPoint)thePoint
{
   return NO;
}
```

It might stop the layer catching touches